# Can't display recycleview items from Firestore in a Fragment

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have made an expense fragment that should display the list of entered expenses into a recycler view, but  it crashes and gives a null pointer exception:

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.kan.fragments.ExpenseFragment.populateExpenseListToUi(ExpenseFragment.kt:90)
at com.example.kan.firebase.FirestoreClass$getExpenseList$1.onSuccess(FirestoreClass.kt:107)
at com.example.kan.firebase.FirestoreClass$getExpenseList$1.onSuccess(FirestoreClass.kt:17)

I've debugged it and the app gets the expense list from the fire store, but for some reason, the recycler view doesent show.

here's my code(Expense Fragment):

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_expense, container, false)

    val addExpenseButton: FloatingActionButton? = view?.findViewById(R.id.fab_add_expense)

    addExpenseButton?.setOnClickListener {
        showCreateExpenseDialog()
        Log.e("FAB", "We see you")

    }


    FirestoreClass().loadFragmentData(this, true)

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view
}
```

My populate list function:

```
fun populateExpenseListToUi(expenseList: ArrayList<Expense>){


    val rvExpenseList: RecyclerView? = view?.findViewById(R.id.rv_expense_list)
    val tvNoExpense: TextView? = view?.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_expenses_available)

    if (expenseList.size > 0){
        Log.e("EXP", "i'm not empty")
       rvExpenseList!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        tvNoExpense!!.visibility = View.GONE
        rvExpenseList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        rvExpenseList.setHasFixedSize(true)

        val adapter = context?.let { ExpenseItemsAdapter(it, expenseList) }
        rvExpenseList.adapter = adapter

        adapter?.setOnClickListener(object : ExpenseItemsAdapter.OnClickListener{
            override fun onClick(position: Int, model: Expense) {
                TODO("Add Expense Details ACtivity")
            }
        })

    }else{
        rvExpenseList!!.visibility = View.GONE
        tvNoExpense!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

my getExpense list function in my firestore class:

```
fun getExpenseList(activity: ExpenseFragment){
    mFireStore.collection(Constants.EXPENSES)
            .whereArrayContains(Constants.USER_ID, getCurrentUserId())
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                document ->
                Log.i(activity.javaClass.simpleName, document.documents.toString())
                val expenseList: ArrayList<Expense> = ArrayList()
                for (i in document.documents){
                    val expense = i.toObject(Expense::class.java)!!
                    expense.documentId = i.id

                    expenseList.add(expense)
                    activity.populateExpenseListToUi(expenseList)
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                e ->
                activity.hideProgressDialog()
                Log.e(activity.javaClass.simpleName,
                "Error while getting expense list.",
                e)
            }
}
```

Comment: Most likely your "activity" object is null, right?

Comment: i don't think so, i have 3 fragments and one dialog fragment connected to the main activity.

Comment: Then at which particular line of code are you getting NPE?

Comment: i get it at this line in the expenseFragment.kt:
 rvExpenseList!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE, when trying to make the recycler view visible. and at 
activity.populateExpenseListToUi(expenseList) in my Firestore class

Comment: But the error says something else. You call "populateExpenseListToUi" on null object reference.

Comment: yes, that particular line is in the "populateExpenseListToUI" function